# update pickerView in previous view controller when closing modal view controller

Tags: ios, core-data, uipickerview

I have a picker view in a view controller A (as inputView of a textfield).
To enable the user to select a new value (one which is not a row of the pickerview yet), there is a button which presents another view controller B modally, where the user can create a new value. Upon closing, I want the textfield and its inputView pickerView to be updated with the new value.
My pickerview is backed by an NSArray from CoreData. Unfortunately the pickerview isn't updated, when I dismiss the View controller B, although the new value is updated in core data.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the good solution is to implement the **delegate pattern** (a common pattern in Cocoa) :

In ViewControllerB.h declare a ViewControllerBDelegate protocol.
Then in your ViewControllerB interface add a delegate as ivar.

```
//ViewControllerB.h

@class ViewControllerB;
@protocol ViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject> 
@required
- (void)viewControllerB:(ViewControllerB *)controller didChangeValueTo:(NSString *)value;
@end

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ViewControllerB> delegate;
[...]
```

Then when the value has changed (or when the user validate the change) send the event to the delegate like this :

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewControllerB:didChangeValueTo:)])
{
    [self.delegate viewControllerB:self didChangeToValue:newValue];
}
```

In ViewControllerA just do

```
ViewControllerB *viewController = [...]; //initialization
[viewController setDelegate:self];
```

and add the method :

```
- (void)viewControllerB:(ViewControllerB *)controller didChangeValueTo:(NSString *)value
{
[...];//your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Tx @Francescu, I guess yours is the correct way "by the book". I used a simplified version, as I already have ViewControllerA as delegate for ViewControllerB. I update the NSArray, which stores my Core Data objects for the pickerview in viewWillAppear, reload the picker view, but have not declared that as a protocoll, as I am not familiar with that in objective-C (coming from Java/Android). However, that works...